# fractions doesn't fit well in longtable cell

Tags: longtable, fractions

I want some fractions in longtable cells. I use this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\hline 
\textbf{Function} & \textbf{Derivative}\\
\hline
$\dfrac{1}{x}$ & $-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$\\
\hline 
\end{longtable} 
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately:

- the upper part of the numerator and
- the lower part of the denominator

are intersected of the `hline`, as you can see below:

[image]

What can I do?

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Maybe you can make use of the cellspace package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to place something invisible that is bigger, but that is hard to do in a consistent manner (`\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex}` for example). The following defines a macro (`\addpad`) that adds 0.5ex of vertical padding on both the height and the depth of its argument (it has an optional argument with which you can change the padding amount).

I also used `\extrarowheight` from the `array` package so that the horizontal rules don't almost touch the upper case letters in normal-height cells.

The following uses `grabbox` so that it should work on arbitrary arguments (including verbatim material), but `grabbox` isn't necessary for the approach to work (see below).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{grabbox}
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox\addpad@Box
\newcommand\addpad[1][.5ex]
  {%
    \leavevmode
    \@grabbox{}\addpad@Box{}\hbox{}
      {%
        \vrule
          height \dimexpr\ht\addpad@Box+#1
          depth 0pt
          width 0pt
        \unhcopy\addpad@Box
        \vrule
          height 0pt
          depth \dimexpr\dp\addpad@Box+#1
          width 0pt
      }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\hline 
\textbf{Function} & \textbf{Derivative}\\
\hline
  \addpad{$\dfrac{1}{x}$} & $-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$\\
\hline 
\end{longtable} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Version without `grabbox`**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}

\newsavebox\addpadBox
\newcommand\addpad[2][.5ex]
  {%
    \sbox\addpadBox{#2}%
    \ht\addpadBox\dimexpr\ht\addpadBox+#1
    \dp\addpadBox\dimexpr\dp\addpadBox+#1
    \usebox\addpadBox
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\hline 
\textbf{Function} & \textbf{Derivative}\\
\hline
  \addpad{$\dfrac{1}{x}$} & $-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$\\
\hline 
\end{longtable} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot!!! Problem solved!

Comment: @KώσταςΚούδας, other answers solves your problem too ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You have for that the  `cellspace` package, which defines *minimal* vertical spacings at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with e the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`. It also works in the amsmath `matrix` environments with the option `[math]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,amsmath}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|Sc|Sc|}
\hline
\textbf{Function} & \textbf{Derivative}\\
\hline
$\dfrac{1}{x}$ & $-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One more (simple) solution with use of the `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell, longtable}
\setcellgapes{5pt}

\begin{document}
{ \makegapedcells
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Function} & \textbf{Derivative}\\
\hline
$\dfrac{1}{x}$ & $-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another possibilty can be using `\arraystretch{...}`, where all the cells have the same vertical lenght.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{3}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\hline 
\textbf{Function} & \textbf{Derivative}\\
\hline

$\dfrac{1}{x}$ & $-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$\\
\hline 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```